# Sound not working after suspend on Lenovo T400

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 on Lenovo T400. Suddenly sound stopped working. It used to work perfectly fine before. I guess, after I suspended my computer (not sure if its first time suspending my computer :P) sound stopped working. I rebooted my system but still of no luck. But headphones are working fine. I tried playing with various sound settings. None of them worked. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure how the problem got fixed. But I will list the set of things I have done so that it may help others.

1)Most importantly - check the sound settings - Output Volume, Mute/UnMute, In Output section and in settings for selected device - make sure speakers are selected in connector,try changing different profiles in hardware section (mine is Analog stereo duplex)

2)I know this is weird solution - But try once :) In some blog, I have read that after suspend some problems may appear - wireless going off, sound not working etc and best solution is to reboot the computer. If it still doesn't work, Suspend it again! I am not saying this works but try once.